# to find the values of gamma distribution knowing the parameter value of a poisson

Tags: probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution

I have a variable X, and information available to me is that the parameter $\theta$ is around 2.2
$X\sim \mathbf{Poisson}(\theta)$

How can I determinate the value of the parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of the prior distribution that is a $Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick values that seem reasonable. A prior distribution reflects the knowledge that you bring to the table. If you know it's near 2.2, you might pick values for the prior such that there is a mean of 2.2 and enough variance that you're comfortable with: large enough to admit values that aren't precisely 2.2, but small enough that the prior actually adds information.

Comment: Thanks @user777, I've chosen a Gamma(13,0.2) so what does it represent the x-axis plotting the distribution?

Comment: The x-axis is in the same units as $X$.

Comment: Yes!, I get it :D